# Input type=time is not working with min and max attributes

Tags: html, input, time

This question might be asked many times. But there is no clear explanation whether it is possible or not.

I have a input with type="time". I have applied min and max attributes to it. But still the picker shows all the time values and it is also possible to select any time value which not in the range.

> ```
> <input type="time" id="gfg" name="Geek_time" placeholder="Enter time" min="16:00" max="22:00">
> ```

I'm checking this on android phone. This also does not work in web chrome browser.
Whereas it works fine with input type="date"

Is this behaviour expected with time input?
Only JS based validation works here and not in-built min/max?

Comment: Possible to share relevent html code?

Comment: @Amit I have tried the sample code provided in w3schools / some other tutorials too

Comment: I think initially you can enter any value but the form will not go through and the validation will fail. Unless you have used event.preventDefault( ) somewhere or you have bypassed the validation somehow.

Comment: Also check for browser version compatibility ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 2):

Below is a very simple html code. Once the html is rendered, you can enter any value you like but the form will not go through. Your browser has to be compatible. Check browser [compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#Browser_compatibility).

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="time" id="gfg" name="Geek_time" placeholder="Enter time" min="16:00" max="22:00">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried entering values outside the range (less than 16:00 or more than 22:00) and then submit the form. It gave errors.

[image: Form validation fails for time less than 16:00 hrs]
[image: Form validation fails for time more than 22:00 hrs]

Comment: But I do not have any form. Just simple html should work.

Comment: Ok I see the reason now. Input is an element of form. If you rather want it for reasons other than form then you will have to take help of JS. Browser may not be able to help you because it is no longer in a form attached to a submit button.

Comment: ok. But it works with type="date" and type="datetime-local"

Comment: I guess because either the dates outside the range are inactive in the calendar or the dates are not rendered in the first place. This is different than validation. The elements are just not there. Time input field is complex, however, because it is hard for the browser to make a complex decision of checking the combination of hours and minutes (if they are not underflowing or overflowing). I guess it takes easier and logical step of deferring the decision till the form is submitted since the form elements are generally part of form. However, you can always write or find JS to do your job.